# Query Dataset to check if row contains any from a set of values

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, conditional, query

For a given keyless dataset, I can query to return the rows whose columns contain a specific value. For example:

```
ds = Dataset[{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}, {"g", "h"}}]
Query[Select[#[[2]] == "f" &]]@ds
```

returns the dataset `{e,f}`.

But, in this simple example, I would like to test:

```
 Query[#[[2]]=="f"||#[[2]]="g"&]]@ds
```

How can I perform this operation without writing out every value of interest. For example, I want check if `#[[2]]` contains any value from the list"check":

```
check={"f","g"}
```

`ds[GroupBy[#[[2]]&][check]` changes the dataset structure. I just want to remove rows from the original dataset.

Comment: You could do `Query[Select[MemberQ[check, #[[2]]] &]]@ds`, for example.

Comment: Slick--I had been trying MemberQ but not implementing it correctly. Please add as an answer so that I can give credit.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin may not see your comment. You can "ping" a user by adding the @ sign before their name, as I did at the beginning of this message. In case he was not interested in converting his comment into an answer, though, I'd urge you to do that yourself (self-answering is encouraged on Stack Exchange) so your question will have a full answer and will be more appealing to future users who encounter similar problems.

Comment: Ok, posted an answer as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Query[Select[MemberQ[check, #[[2]]] &]] @ ds
```